# React jest & enzyme testing. How to correctly pass video source to <video/>

Tags: reactjs, testing, video, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test whether the 'video' component loaded video correctly. I created 'videoStream' ref for 'video' component :

```
<video ref={videoStream} width="100%" preload="auto">
   <source src={this.props.video_source} type={this.props.file_type}/>
</video>
```

In my videoPlayer.test.js :

```
wrapper = mount(<VideoPlayer video_source={"/video_samples/video.mp4"} file_type={"video/mp4"}/>);
describe('Video player', () => {
    it('should correctly load video', async () => {
            jest.useFakeTimers();
            setTimeout(() => {
                expect(wrapper.instance().videoStream.current).toBeDefined();
                expect(wrapper.instance().videoStream.current.duration).toBeGreaterThan(0);
              }, 4500);
            jest.runAllTimers();
        });
    }
```

/video_samples/video.mp4 is stored inside public folder.

When starting project with 'npm start', video loads correctly and duration is 15. But when i do 'npm test', duration is always 0. It should be more than 0.

I guess the problem with passing source to VideoPlayer. Help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDom that Jest uses under the hood, does not simulate all the browser's features. Among others, `<video>` is not fully supported.

You may extend [VideoHTMLElement manually](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/464#issuecomment-200551245) to simulate logic you want to test.

Or you can just rethink you test to avoid testing that.

In your particular case I believe there is no need to test that with unit test, you may include it for manual or Selenium-based testing instead.